# Open all pdf documents in a new tab with a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser, popup

I have a problem with popup blockers and `window.open` in chrome (Microsoft Edge works). 
I read that browser allows window.open only with user interaction, so only the first pdf is opened:

```
//Show all pdf
$scope.showPdf = function(pdfList){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < pdfList.length; i++){
        window.open(document.getElementById(pdfList[i].name).href, '_blank');
    }
}
```

In HTML code I have:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;"></i> 
    <a id="{{pdf.name}}" data-ng-href="pdf/{{pdf.id}}/{{pdf.name}}" target="_blank"><span> </span>{{pdf.name}}</a>
</div>
<button id="pdfButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
   data-ng-click="showPdf(pdfList)">Show all</button>
```

Is there a workaround to open all my files in a new tab? Thanks